# RegExp: Determine if previous Line above match contains text

Tags: javascript, regex

Given the following line of text:

```
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse lacinia 
convallis ornare. 
<code>function js() {
     return $this->_js;
}
</code>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse lacinia 
convallis ornare."
```

I want to determine if the line above `<code>` is a text line or a blank newline.  If there is text, then I will add an additional newline so that there is an empty line between the code and text.  If not, then carry on.

**this**

```
"Suspendisse lacinia convallis ornare
<code>function js(){...."
```

**would turn to this**

```
"Suspendisse lacinia convallis ornare

<code>function js(){...."
```

Is there a simple way to do this given that there are no *look-behinds* in JavaScript?

Comment: I was writing almost exactly the same code but you are the fastest Wiktor ;) This is the way to do it !

Comment: Done @WiktorStribiżew, time to sleep for me too ^^

Comment: The simple way: `str.replace(/(\S)\n?(<code>)/, "$1\n\n$2")`

Comment: @revo does not work if text ends with one or more space as `\S` exclude this char. Use `(\S\s+?)\n?(<code>)` instead ;)

Comment: Then, if that's likely to happen, I believe OP would be able to modify it a little bit, fitting the case. @stej4n

Comment: In the question, the first phrase already ends with a dot followed by a space ^^

Comment: Yet my comment is valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the simpliest way to achieve this :

All credit goes to Wiktor Stribiżew (checkout his comment in OP)

**Sample snippet**

```js
const s = `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse lacinia 
convallis ornare. 
<code>function js() {
     return $this->_js;
}
</code>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse lacinia 
convallis ornare.`;

let rx = /(\S[^\S\r\n]*\n)(<code>)/g;
console.log(s.replace(rx, "$1\n$2"));
```

Comment: Thank you @stej4n and Wiktor for your help.  Nothing like waking up and being able to fix this right away. :)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to just use a capture group which you then re-use in the replacement

```
/([^\n\r])(\n\r?)(?:<code>)/g
```

This matches a non-newline followed by a newline and then `<code>`.

If you replace the matches with group 1 and two times group two, you end up with the desired double newline, and it leaves all non-matching input intact.

```
text.replace(/([^\n\r])(\n\r?)(?:<code>)/g, '$1$2$2');
```

[a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/foozle/k2mnn83f/) for your convenience